# ¿Qué significa "de pe a pa"?

Tags: definiciones, modismos

¿Cúal es el significado de la siguiente expresión "de pe a pa"?

Por ejemplo:

> Tienes que aprenderte esto de pe a pa.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

El DRAE nos da la definición precisa, en la [entrada para "pe"](http://dle.rae.es/pe):

> de ~ a pa.
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Enteramente, desde el principio al fin.

Así, tu ejemplo sería

> Tienes que aprenderte esto de pe a pa.
>
> Tienes que aprenderte esto de principio a fin.

Una expresión con significado similar, también muy usada para significar *de principio a fin* es *de cabo a rabo*.

Answer (score 20):

Gonzalo ya respondió sobre el significado. Sobre la antigüedad de la expresión (muy difundida en todo el ámbito hispano hablante) y su origen, ver [aquí](https://capsuladelengua.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/de-pe-a-pa/).

> En La Celestina, obra escrita por Fernando de Rojas en el año 1499, se lee el siguiente fragmento:
>   “Yo te juro por el santo martirologio de pe a pa, el brazo me tiembla de lo que por ella entiendo hazer…”.
>   En estas líneas, “jurar por el santo martirologio de pe a pa”, se entiende como: jurar por todos los mártires de la iglesia, desde el primero hasta el último.
>
> Años después, en 1627, en Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales, obra escrita por  Gonzalo Correas, aparece esta definición:
>
> “De pe a pa: Decir las cosas distintas y claras. Palabra por Palabra:”
>
> Pero, ¿de dónde surgió tan intrigante expresión?…  Cuando no había imprenta, si se quería hacer copias de algún texto no quedaba más que echárselas a mano, y esa era la chamba de los copistas que, como sello de calidad, cuando terminaban su trabajo al pie ponían la frase  “de palabra a palabra” como garantía de que habían hecho una copia fiel; al ser una fórmula muy recurrente, usaron la abreviación:
>
> de P. a P.
>
> Bastaría un pequeño desliz fonético para convertir esta abreviación en la expresión “de pe a pa”, guardando el mismo sentido de “palabra a palabra”, tal como lo indicó Correas en 1627; ampliando después su significado a “con todo detalle”, tal como hoy la usamos.